# Unit testing nodejs events

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, events, mocha.js

I'm using a solution explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826352/whats-the-best-way-to-unit-test-an-event-being-emitted-in-nodejs) to unit test events in my node application.

However, the setTimeout function never calls and so my tests pass when they should fail.

Here is an example:

```
suite('myTests', function() {
    test('myFunction_whenCalled_emitsEvent', function() {
        var myClass = new MyClass();
            var eventTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                assert(false);
            }, 1000);
            myClass.on('something', function() {
                clearTimeout(eventTimeout);
            });
            myClass.doSomething(); // this does not emit the 'something' event
    });
});
```

I would expect this to fail, after 1 second as long as the 'something' event is not raised.

I put a breakpoint in the `assert(false)` line and it is never hit.

Could someone point me in the right direction ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the `done` callback to show that your test is finished. Something like this:

```
suite('myTests', function() {
    test('myFunction_whenCalled_emitsEvent', function(done) {
        var myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.on('something', function() {
            done();
        });
        myClass.doSomething();
    });
});
```

It looks like you are only testing whether the event is emitted. If this is the case, then the whole `setTimeout` thing is unnecessary. Mocha will itself timeout if it does not get `done` without the default timeout (2000ms, if I recall correctly).

The way your code was set, Mocha would just schedule your event and then exit the test. Since *scheduling* the event was successful, Mocha would call the test successful.

Comment: Hello Louis. Thank you for the answer. I changed my code, and the don() call is not being hit as expected, however the test still passes. It looks like all tests run and exit after around 12ms. Is there something I need to do to make sure it checks for the done() before exiting ? Thank you again.

Comment: Actually, I think the issue is with something else. If the test passes with the code I have in my answer, then it means that ``done()`` **is** called because Mocha **will** complain if ``done()`` is not called within the timeout period. Now, if there is something that does ``setTimeout`` elsewhere (in your application or a library you are using) then this may delay Mocha's exiting.

Comment: If I have tests that run prior to this test that use setTimeout, without calling done, could that cause this issue ?

Comment: Possibly but it is hard to tell from here. One thing you could do is isolate just this test in a separate file and run mocha on it and see how it behaves. If it runs file and does not delay before exiting, then you know the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for you continued support on this ! I will continue to investigate with your help.